# How to add to five POP3 email accounts?

Tags: gmail, pop3

I currently have five POP3 emails in my Gmail account. I need to add four more POP3 accounts.

Is there any way to add more POP3 accounts to my Gmail or do I need to create a Google Apps account - or what are the possibilities?

Answer (score 2):

From [Check email from other accounts with Gmail - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?hl=en)

> You can add up to 5 accounts, including Gmail and other email
>   providers.

One alternative is, instead of using POP to get the email messages, configure the other accounts to automatically forward the new email messages to your Gmail account.